# C++ "error: "object missing in reference to ..." depends on gcc version

Tags: c++, gcc

I am facing a compilation error with one gcc version (4.3.2), whereas the same code will be compiled without complaints with a newer version of gcc, e.g. 4.5.2.

The following example illustrates the problem:

```
class Base {
  protected:
    int member;
};

template<typename T>
class A : public Base {
};

template<typename T>
class C : public A<T> {
    C() {
        Base::member = 1;
    }
};

int main() {
}
```

For 4.3.2 I am getting:

```
test.cpp: In constructor 'C<T>::C()':
test.cpp:4: error: object missing in reference to 'Base::member'
test.cpp:14: error: from this location
```

For 4.5.2 it compiles just fine.

If one compiler version accepts the code it cannot be completely wrong. My guess is that it conforms to the C++ standard, but the older compiler was lacking a proper implementation of the same.

1. What exactly is the problem?
2. Is there a portable way of writing that kind of code such that as much compilers as possible accept it?

Comment: I found this into 4.5 release note: G++ now implements DR 176. Previously G++ did not support using the injected-class-name of a template base class as a type name, and lookup of the name found the declaration of the template in the enclosing scope. Now lookup of the name finds the injected-class-name, which can be used either as a type or as a template, depending on whether or not the name is followed by a template argument list. [link_to_release_note](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html)

Comment: @LPs I don't think that's relevant since `Base` isn't a "template base class". edit: Unless it gets confused by the *intermediate* template base class?

Comment: `If one compiler version accepts the code it cannot be completely wrong.`
Alas, it doesn't work like that. In fact, the C++ standard has quite a few rules about when a C++ program is ill-formed. A conforming C++ compiler is required to emit a diagnostic (error/warning/other message). If a compiler does not emit an error for an ill-formed program, that's a bug in the compiler (so now you have two problems: in your program AND the compiler).

Comment: @ Mark B: I guess...

Comment: @Bulletmagnet `A conforming C++ compiler is required to emit a diagnostic (error/warning/other message). If a compiler does not emit an error for an ill-formed program, that's a bug in the compiler`... Wouldn't that mean that 4.5.2 is more buggy than 4.3.2 (as it accepts the code)? To me this rather hints that  the code *not* ill-formed, as I believe gcc will evolve towards better conformance.

Comment: Sorry, I was speaking hypothetically. Your code is accepted by clang (3.7.0) so it's very likely correct. That means GCC 4.5.2 is better (at least in this regard :-) than 4.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in the earlier version of g++ but the solution is simple: Just add `this->` to the expression, as `this->Base::member = 1;` which unconfuses the compiler.

Comment: I accept this as answer as it works for me. Thanks! Still I do not really understand where to compiler gets confused. So this is yet another field like dependent names. It is not so easy to grasp and you run into it too infrequently to keep it in mind. So usually I find myself with a handful of 'typename's that I put into the code wherever it seems fit until it compiles...